# Regex for a Microsoft Word search

Tags: regex, image, search, ms-word, field

I am editing an large book document with a lot of picture. I have a number of sections in the text with fields similar to this:

```
{INCLUDEPICTURE  "C:\\book\\NikonD5500\\chapter_1-129.jpg" \d}
```

I am trying to run a regex find and copy that will find any phrase between the two curly bracket {} and paste it in an other document. Ideally I only need the picture names like "chapter_1-129.jpg" (and so on) as a list.

Comment: It seems you forgot to include a question in your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can run a simple VBA macro that iterates all fields in the document like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ListImageFields()

    Dim oField As Field
    Dim oDocSource As Document
    Dim oDocTarget As Document

    Dim result As String

    For Each oField In ActiveDocument.Fields
        If oField.Type = wdFieldIncludePicture Then
            result = result & GetPictureSourceFromFieldCode(oField.code) & vbCrLf
        End If
    Next

    Set oDocTarget = Documents.Add
    oDocTarget.Range.Text = result

End Sub

Function GetPictureSourceFromFieldCode(ByVal fieldCode As String) As String

    Dim startIndex As Integer
    Dim endIndex As Integer

    startIndex = InStr(fieldCode, """") + 1
    endIndex = InStrRev(fieldCode, """")
    GetPictureSourceFromFieldCode = Mid(fieldCode, startIndex, endIndex - startIndex)

End Function
```